# Plot data that retrieved from Firebase-Database (Realtime)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, plotly, graph-visualization

I've a problem with plotting an **number array** in *Plotly*. So, we can skip to subject without further ado.

Here is HTML code:

```
<script src="plotly.min.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <div class="navbar"><span>Analog Plotter by remidosol</span></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="chart"></div>


    <script src="FireConfig.js"></script>    
    <script>

        Plotly.plot('chart',[{
            y:[analogval()],
            type:'line'
        }]);

        var cnt = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            Plotly.extendTraces('chart',{ y:[[analogval()]]}, [0]);
            cnt++;
            if(cnt > 300) {
                Plotly.relayout('chart',{
                    xaxis: {
                        range: [cnt-300,cnt]
                    }
                });
            }
        },15);
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I plot number ARRAY that read from **Firebase**? I changed getData function's return code, once.(like I placed a num array parameter to getData, but it didn't make the plot.ly code work to plot data).
**I could read data from Firebase but i couldn't plot it.**

Here is view of my website and console:
[It reads data but can't plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M04aK.png)

Would you help me please? What's wrong with this code? *BTW, Firebase config block is okay, i changed it before create this subject.*
I'm waiting for your help. Thank you from now.




**Edit:**
I can get data and convert it to number by replace and slice methods. It's correct now. But the plot.ly code still don't plot data line.

Following aforementioned function, here is the code below:

```
function analogval(){ 
    databaseiot.orderByChild("analog").on('value', function(dataSnapshot) { 
        var arru = dataSnapshot.val().analog;
        arru.toString();
        arru = arru.replace(/\\r/g,'');
        arru = arru.slice(1, 4);
        arru = Number(arru);
        console.log(arru);
        return arru;
        //arru = data.val().analog.split(",").map(Number); 
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `analogval()` function. If I'm not mistaken, your current implementation of `analogval ()` doesn't return anything. Your return statement is inside of the callback function that you passed to the `.on()` method. What you need is to have your `analogval()` function to return the value of the array.

One way to do this is to create a variable (e.g. `array`) visible to `analogval()` and set the value of `array` to be what you read from Firebase, then return `array` from `analogval()`:

```
var array;
function analogval(){ 
databaseiot.orderByChild("analog").on('value', function(dataSnapshot) { 
    var arru = dataSnapshot.val().analog;
    arru.toString();
    arru = arru.replace(/\\r/g,'');
    arru = arru.slice(1, 4);
    arru = Number(arru);
    console.log(arru);
    array = arru;
});
return array;
}
```